# Getting file info from memory stream

Tags: c#, webapi

I am trying to make webapi which returns image

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult GetCheckInPhoto(int checkInId, string dealerNr, int photoIndex, int photoType)
{
    var stream = _checkinService.GetCheckInPhoto(checkInId, dealerNr, photoIndex, photoType);

    return new MultipartResult(){
        new MultipartContent()
        {
            ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg,
            Name = "xxx",
            FileName = "dsada",
            Stream = stream
        }
    };
}
```

My method `GetCheckInPhoto` returns `MemoryStream` where is photo.

how to get `FileInfo` like `Filename` or `FileType` from `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Simply put: you can't. Your method will need to return additional information.

Comment: A memorystream is just a stream of bytes. Is this photo stored on disk, or in a database? If it's on disk, then you don't need memorystream to retrieve it, you can just get the file object directly with all the info in it. If it's in the database, then hopefully you stored info like the filename in some other columns in the database table? In that case, your getCheckInPhoto method needs to return an object of some type which contains both the memorystream and also the other fields. If you didn't store a filename, then you can just create a random one for the purpose of the download.

Answer (score 3):

Your "CheckinService" should return something like

```
public class MyFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public Stream ReadStream { get; set; }
}
```